# How can one get involved in the Ubuntu Brainstorm team?

Tags: community, brainstorm

I've heard it thrown around on a lot of blogs that Ubuntu Brainstorm is the "graveyard of good ideas". I have a bit of a passion for average end-users suggesting the kinds of software they want and they way they think their applications and computers could work. I'm interested in joining the Ubuntu Brainstorm team, maybe to facilitate ideas not getting buried and making it not seem like a dead platform. Unfortunately I'm not very plugged into the "community" so I'm not sure how to go about it. I was hoping someone might be able to point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: After years of great discussion, Ubuntu Brainstorm closed permanently in 2014.

Comment: This question was from 6 years ago...

Comment: Yes, that's why I noted when it closed, and flagged the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great idea, I had a few ideas myself. You can start at http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/, there are lots of ideas being voted for. Also [HERE](https://launchpad.net/~brainstorm-moderators) is a link to brainstorm moderators.
There is also [Ubuntu QA Team mailing-list](http://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-qa) you can join.
good luck.

Comment: Well I'm more talking about how to actually get involved reviving the platform, not just contributing to it. Like do they need more moderators on the site? If so how could one go about applying for that?

Comment: I guess I'd go for Ubuntu QA Team on the mailing list, there you can contact them directly.

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to contact the Brainstorm Moderators on their [mailing list](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/brainstorm-moderators) (or contact me, I'm currently a Brainstorm admin).

Brainstorm has a lot of good ideas, and good moderation. What we need right now are liasons, volunteers who participate in both Brainstorm and other projects, who can discuss those projects authoritatively with idea submitters and help translate good ideas into useful plans and milestones in their projects.

Of course, if you have a good idea, we'll happily discuss it.